How to determine whether the following two notions of "partial associativity" are inequivalent
Definitions:

Given a triple $(S,T,\cdot)$, let us say $(S,T,\cdot)$ has property $R$ if $S$ is a set, $T \subseteq (S \times S)$ is a relation from $S$ to itself, and $\cdot : T \rightarrow S$ is a function denoted $(a,b) \mapsto a \cdot b$.

We think of $\cdot$ as a "partial operation" on $S$, and $T$ as the set of "multipliable pairs" of elements of $S$.

Given a triple $(S,T,\cdot)$, let us say it has property $P$ if it has property $R$ and if
for any $a,b,c \in S$, if $(a,b),(b,c) \in T$, and if $(a \cdot b,c) , (a,b\cdot c) \in T$, then $(a\cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot (b\cdot c)$.
Given a triple $(S,T,\cdot)$, let us say it has property $Q$ if it has property $R$ and if
for any $a,b,c \in S$, if $(a,b),(b,c) \in T$,
then $(a \cdot b,c) , (a,b\cdot c) \in T$
and $(a\cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot (b\cdot c)$.

We think of $P$ and $Q$ as "associativity conditions", but imposed on slightly different classes of "multipliable triples" $(a,b,c)$.

We note $Q$ implies $P$ straightforwardly.
My question is:

What would be an example of a triple $(S,T,\cdot)$ having property $P$ but not $Q$ (or, if no such example exists, how could this be proved)?


Remark: I think if $(S,T,\cdot)$ were obtained from a "category without identity morphisms" $C$, with $S$ the set of morphisms of $C$ and $T$ the set of "composable pairs" of morphisms, and $\cdot$ the composition, then $(S,T,\cdot)$ would necessarily satisfy condition $Q$.
I am wondering what would be (if it exists) a triple $(S,T,\cdot)$ having property $P$ but not $Q$, therefore not admitting a description by a category without identities.
(Note: the definition of $R$ and $P$ are taken from notes posted online, and the idea described in the above remark is based on the notes; unfortunately, no author was written, and I can't find a link to them.)

What about $S={0,1}$, $T={(1,1)}$, $1\cdot1=0$?

Consider $S=\mathbb Q$, $T=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q\mid x+y\in\mathbb Z\}$ and $a\cdot b=a+b$.
Now if $(a,b), (b,c)\in T$, then $a+b\in\mathbb Z$ and $b+c\in\mathbb Z$.
Property $P$: If $(a\cdot b,c), (a,b\cdot c)\in T$, then $(a+b)+c\in\mathbb Z$ and $a+(b+c)\in\mathbb Z$. By associativity of addition in $\mathbb Q$, these are equal. Thus property $P$ holds.
Property $Q$: Consider $a=\frac13=c, b=\frac23$. Then $a+b=1\in\mathbb Z, b+c=1\in\mathbb Z$ implying $(a,b),(b,c)\in T$ but $(a\cdot b, c)=(a+b)+c=\frac43\notin\mathbb Z$ and hence $(a\cdot b,c)\notin T$. Thus property $\mathbb Q$ does not hold.
